# Symfony : ignore some route

Tags: symfony, vuejs2, vue-resource

I want use Symfony4 with Vuejs app in the same corner of my server (on the same domaine) 
But Sf routing is master and (than VueJs router) generate some 404

```
mode: 'history',
```

using the history mode.

Thanks for your tricks ;) .

Answer (score 1):

**approach number 1:**

routing configuration to have a "jolly" route:

this route MUST be latest to match

```
jolly_all_in:
    path: '/{jolly}'
    controller: 'App\Controller\JollyController::allInPrintVueInit'
    requirements:
        jolly: '.*'
```

or in this case all your vue route MUST has a prefix "your-vue-route-prefix"

```
jolly_all_in_with_prefix:
    path: '/your-vue-route-prefix/{jolly}'
    controller: 'App\Controller\JollyController::allInPrintVueInit'
    requirements:
        jolly: '.*'
```

with this approach you must manage your 404 from JS.

**approach number 2:**

you MUST map all your JS route to symfony route.

example

```
user_list:
    path: '/user'
    controller: 'App\Controller\VueController::printVueInit'

user_get:
    path: '/user/{id}'
    controller: 'App\Controller\VueController::printVueInit'
    requirements:
        id: '\d+'

[...]:
    path: '/.../.../...'    
    controller: 'App\Controller\VueController::printVueInit'
```